# Transitivity on a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I have a question about equivalence relationships.
I know that a relationship is an equivalence relationship when the reflexive property, symmetric property and the transitive property exists on a set.

Ok...! ;-)

I have the following set

```
A = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

With the following relationship:

```
R = {(3, 3),(4, 0),(0, 0),(0, 4),(1, 1),(1, 6),(6, 1),(2, 2),(4, 4),(5, 5),(6, 6),(5, 3),(3, 5)}
```

With this data, we can draw the digraph:

[Digraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sv34.jpg)

Then it's easy to check that the transitive property isn't exist in this case.
is it true?
and.., if is it true the question is... what kind of relationship is?

Answer (score 0):

It is an equivalence relation, since it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. If you think that it is *not* transitive, then please provide an example of elements $a,b,c\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ such that $(a,b),(b,c)\in R$, but $(a,c)\notin R$.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your fast answer! did you see the digraph? I think that is reflexive, symmetric but... I can't "see" the transitive property. Why do you say it is transitive?

Comment: I mean, I didn't find any relationship where $${\displaystyle \forall a,b,c\in A:\quad aRb\quad \land \quad bRc\longrightarrow \quad aRc}$$ Then, this particular case, is not an equivalence relationship, but I am not pretty sure...

Comment: I wrote in my answer that is *is* an equivalence relation. Do you think that I am going to change my mind all of a sudden? Besides, I have no clue about the reason you think otherwise. Not no mention that I have no idea about the meaning of the first sentence from your previous comment.

Answer (score -1):

If you add for example (1, 0) and (0, 1) to R then it won't be transitive since (0, 1), (1, 6) ∈ R but (0, 6) ∉ R. That way it will not be an equivalence relation.

Comment: That's true, but, with the current digraph posted in my question, the set doesn't satisfy the transitivity property, really?

Comment: Your diagraph visually satisfies transitive property.  Remember that elements a, b and c in the definition of transitive property doesn't need to be different.